# Как реализовать поэтапный переход страниц?

Tags: php, html

Нужно сделать поэтапный переход от страницы к странице на сайте таким образом, чтобы пользователь не мог оказаться, например, на 3 странице, не пройдя 1 и 2 страницы. Более того, даже если он сохранит 3 страницу в закладках браузера, то при заходе все равно попадет на 1-ю. Но при этом нужно оставить возможность во время перехода нажимать на кнопку "вернуться на страницу назад".
Как пример - что-то подобное сделано в онлайн-тестах. Там такое же поэтапное продвижение по вопросам.
Странички сайта на сессии, вот с такой проверкой:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("bd.php");
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; } //id "хозяина" странички
else
{ exit("Вы зашли на страницу без параметра!");} //если не указали id,то выдаем ошибку
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
exit("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL</p>");
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
{
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'",$db); 
$myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
if (empty($myrow2['id']))
   {
   exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
   }
}
else {
exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!"); }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (empty($myrow['login'])) { exit("Пользователя не существует! Возможно он был удален.");} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея примерно такая - например на всех страницах пишется что-то типа:

---

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['justCommed'])) {
// если $_SESSION['justCommed'] не инициализирована
     header('Location:/defaultPage.php');// делаем переадресацию на дефолтную страницу
}
```

---

Ну а в defaultPage.php вы уже присваиваете значение для `$_SESSION['justCommed']` в `true`, соответственно - если пользователь зайдет на любую из страниц где описана проверка `$_SESSION['justCommed']` он всегда будет переадресован на `defaultPage.php`.

---

В общем и целом идея примерно такая, чтобы думать более конкретно нужна конкретная задача и конкретный код. В любом случае, ИМХО, лучше всего, реализовывать подобную задачу с использованием сессии

Comment: Проапдейтила первый пост. У меня странички на сессиях, куда можно вставить ваш кусочек? Выше проверки id?